# SP2013 List Workflow Action

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to write an action using the "If any value equals any value" workflow action.

See screenshot below. I'm trying to make sure the workflow doesn't update anything unless the Closed Date is empty. As in blank, null, "". Of course, SPD won't allow this, or I simply don't know the syntax.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution #1 :**

As a workaround, You can achieve it by steps below:

- Create an empty date field in list
- Set it as hidden field
- In SPD, compare your field with this hidden empty date field.

[Click here for more details on how to set field as hidden and use it in SPD](https://howardmcd.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/how-to-check-if-a-date-field-is-blank-in-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Solution #2:

- Convert the date to a short date
- Store the date in a string workflow variable
- Compare the string workflow variable to "1/1/0001"

[More information here](https://cliffchaney.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/empty-or-null-dates-in-sharepoint-2010/)